# omp max reduction with storage of index

Tags: c++, reduction, openmp

Using c++ openmp 3.1 I implemented a max reduction which stores the maximum value of integer variable (score) of an vector of objects (s). But I also want to store the vector index to acces the (s) object with the maximum score.
My current unsuccesfull implementation looks like this:

```
//s is a vector of sol objects which contain apart from other variables an  integer     score    variable s[].score            
int bestscore = 0;
int bestant = 0;                
#pragma omp parallel shared(bestant)
{//start parallel session
    #pragma omp for    nowait reduction(max : bestscore)
    for (int ant = 0; ant<maxsols; ++ant) // for all ants
    {
        //procedures on s[ant] object which update the  int s[ant].score
        if (s[ant].score > bestscore)
        {
            //find the object with the highest score
            bestscore = s[ant].score;
            bestant = ant;//i also want know which ant has the highest score
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles and runs. the maximum bestscore is found but bestant gets a random index. The ant linked to the fastest thread to finish gets stored in bestant.
bestscore start with a value of 0 so in most cases s[ant].score will have a higher score and bestscore and bestant are updated.
 I think I need a reduction operator for bestant like "on update of bestscore".

Comment: And what is your problem? What happens when you compile/link/run that code? Are there any errors or crashes? Have you tried to debug it? Do you haven an actual *question* to ask?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950056/how-to-parallel-nested-loop-to-find-the-nearest-two-point-in-openmp/23957676#23957676

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I think the OP stated his problem "but bestant gets a random index".  I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason (as you suspect) why `bestant` gets a random index `i` is because `bestant` is shared and does not benefit from the reduction clause as `bestscore` does. The solution proposed by Z boson is fine: the `critical` instruction block is executed only once by thread so that the overhead should be limited.

You were using a OpenMP 3.1 runtime at that time. I wanted to post to explain that this limitation has been addressed since OpenMP 4.0. You can now write a [user defined operator](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html) (see *2.19.5.7 declare reduction Directive*).

In your case, a solution can be to pack the two values in a struct and
define how two such struct elements combine in the end of the `#pragma parallel for` loop.

```c
//s is a vector of sol objects which contain apart from other variables an  integer     score    variable s[].score

typedef struct {
  int score;
  int ant;
} best_t;

best_t best = { 0, 0 };

// we declare our user reduction operator :
// it is called get_max, return a a value of type best_t.
// omp_out and omp_in are the predefined names of two private elements
// to combine in the end to the final shared variable.

#pragma omp declare reduction(get_max : best_t :\
    omp_out = omp_out.score > omp_in.score ? omp_out : omp_in)\
    initializer (omp_priv=(omp_orig))

                
#pragma omp parallel 
{//start parallel session
    #pragma omp for    nowait reduction(get_max : best)
    for (int ant = 0; ant<maxsols; ++ant) // for all ants
    {
        //procedures on s[ant] object which update the  int s[ant].score
        if (s[ant].score > best.score)
        {
            //find the object with the highest score
            best.score = s[ant].score;
            best.ant = ant;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int bestscore = 0;
int bestant = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int bestscore_private = 0;
    int bestant_private = 0;
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for (int ant = 0; ant<maxsols; ++ant) {         
        if (s[ant].score > bestscore_private) {
            bestscore_private = s[ant].score;
            bestant_private = ant;
        }
    }
    #pragma omp critical 
    {
        if(bestscore_private>bestscore) {
            bestscore = bestscore_private;
            bestant = besant_private;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, due to the critical zone this offers no speed improvement in comparison to sequentially looking up the best ant. But I will keep it in mind when I need to scale up my code (higher values of maxsol)

Comment: I got over 30% performance gain thanks to your solution (compared to originally almost the same as OP's code)

Answer (score 0):

Two observations:

- I think you only need to compare `bestscore_private` to `bestscore` when its value is changed, this way the number of comparisons is reduced.
- Also, at least in todays omp you can utilize a critical section **inside** the if conditional, this way comparisons between `bestscore_private` a `bestscore` would be carried out in parallel and the infrequent (hope so) update to `bestscore` will be carried out in a critical manner.

  int bestscore = 0;
    int bestant = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {

  ```
    int bestscore_private = 0;
    int bestant_private = 0;
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for (int ant = 0; ant<maxsols; ++ant) {         
        if (s[ant].score > bestscore_private) {
            bestscore_private = s[ant].score;
            bestant_private = ant;   
            if(bestscore_private>bestscore){   
              #pragma omp critical 
              {

              bestscore = bestscore_private;
              bestant = besant_private;
              }
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: You could follow examples where this is implemented with nested loops (and locally defined reduction variables for the inner loop), so that the critical need not be in the inner loop. This is natural for a 2D array.  In principle, the inner loop might be a  user defined simd reduction, but I haven't seen that done effectively.